# How do 尤's 2021 meanings appertain to 尢?

Tags: etymology

I can't read Chinese, and don't understand [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%99%B7).  How does [尢](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%A2) († lame; crippled) relate to 尤 (especially, particularly)? [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E5%B0%A4#).

[image]

Comment: Uhh...that Yellowbridge entry is confusing, 尢 is not a functional component of 尤, it is a shape that happens to share the same form as the part of 尤 without the dot. That dictionary doesn’t have clear entries...

Answer (score 2):

尢 and 尤 are not related at all.

尢 is a crippled man with deformed legs as contrasted with the man in 大 having straight legs. Thus it means lame or crippled.
This character is no longer used in modern scripture and is written as 尪 with an additional 王 phonetic component.

尤 is possibly a variant form of hand 又 with an extra stroke probably representing a wound or wart which later became 疣.
Origins for 尤 is unclear to me though, but 又 is definitely a part of 尤.